# Getting "Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list)."

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

For the whole week I have been training my AI model, but it is facing some issue of "Failed to convert NumPy array to a tensor my".

I'm using the dataset I created for this model containing 100k+ movie plots, but again and again it’s showing the same issue when I call "model.fit(...)"

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEzOQ.png)

This is the code I'm using

```
# Importing the dataset
filename = "MoviePlots.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding= 'unicode_escape')

# Keeping only the necessary columns
data = data[['Plot']]

# Keep only rows where 'Plot' is a string
data = data[data['Plot'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]

# Clean the data
data['Plot'] = data['Plot'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
data['Plot'] = data['Plot'].apply((lambda x: re.sub('[^a-zA-z0-9\s]', '', x)))

# Create the tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000, split=" ")
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data['Plot'].values)

# Save the tokenizer
with open('tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# Create the sequences
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data['Plot'].values)
Y = pad_sequences(X)

# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(5000, 256, input_length=Y.shape[1]))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1)))
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))
model.add(LSTM(256, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.1))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(Dense(5000, activation='softmax'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(X, X, epochs=500, batch_size=256, verbose=1)
```

I have tried several other methods, but the issue remains the same.

```
epochs=500
model.fit(X, X, verbose=2)
```

Comment: It looks like the issue you're facing is related to the data that you're using as input to your model. Based on the code you've provided, it looks like you're trying to fit your model on the same data for both the input and target values (i.e., you're calling model.fit(X, X, ...)). This is likely causing an error because the shapes of the input and target data are not compatible.

Comment: Can you provide/[edit] in some more information on the dataset you are using? I imagine it's quite large, so provide only enough to help you to debug it. It looks like we need to know the shape of the data.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible ways. One of them is to create it as a dataset, as your error message indicated a mismatched datatype for model.fit().

Sample: Transform an input word by vocab and match their string bytes, or tokenize them.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_text as tft

import json

input_word = tf.constant(' \'Cause it\'s easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand into the dirt Easy as an ice cream sundae Every dancer gets a little hurt Easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand into the dirt Easy as an ice cream sundae Every dancer gets a little hurt Easy as an ice cream sundae Oh, easy as an ice cream sundae ')
vocab = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_",
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab)
sequences_mapping_string = layer(tf.strings.bytes_split(input_word))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Method 1 create label from map it with vocabulary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
print( 'input_word: ' + str(input_word) )
print( " " )
print( tf.strings.bytes_split(input_word) )
print( sequences_mapping_string )

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Method 2 create label from it tokenizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
text = "Cause its easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand"
tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=10000, oov_token='oov', filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n', lower=True,)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts([text])

i_count = tf.strings.split([text])[0].shape[0] + 1
aDict = json.loads(tokenizer.to_json())
text_input = tf.constant([''], shape=())

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
def auto_paddings( data, max_sequences=15 ):
    data = tf.constant( data, shape=(data.shape[0], 1) )
    paddings = tf.constant([[1, 15 - data.shape[0] - 1], [0, 0]])
    padd_data = tf.pad( data, paddings, "CONSTANT" )
    padd_data = tf.constant( padd_data, shape=(15, 1) ).numpy()
    return padd_data


input_word = tf.zeros([1, 15, 1], dtype=tf.int64)
input_label = tf.ones([1, 1, 1], dtype=tf.int64)

for i in range(i_count):
    word = json.loads(aDict['config']['index_word'])[str(i + 1)]
    i_word = layer(tf.strings.bytes_split(word))
    padd_data = tf.constant(auto_paddings( i_word, 15 ), shape=(1, 15, 1))

    index = json.loads(aDict['config']['word_index'])[word]

    if i > 0:
        input_word = tf.experimental.numpy.vstack([input_word, padd_data])
        input_label = tf.experimental.numpy.vstack([input_label, tf.constant(index, shape=(1, 1, 1))])


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(( input_word, input_label ))
for d in dataset:
    print(d)

print( " ==================================================== " )
```

Output: Input word as a string

```
input_word: tf.Tensor(b" 'Cause it's easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand into the dirt Easy as an ice cream sundae Every dancer gets a little hurt Easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand into the dirt Easy as an ice cream sundae Every dancer gets a little hurt Easy as an ice cream sundae Oh, easy as an ice cream sundae ", shape=(), dtype=string)
```

Output: String to bytes as a splitters.

```
tf.Tensor(
[b' ' b"'" b'C' b'a' b'u' b's' b'e' b' ' b'i' b't' b"'" b's' b' ' b'e'
 b'a' b's' b'y' b' ' b'a' b's' b' ' b'a' b'n' b' ' b'i' b'c' b'e' b' '
  ...
 b'n' b'd' b'a' b'e' b' '], shape=(327,), dtype=string)
```

Output: Sequence mapping a string to phones.

```
tf.Tensor(
[ 0  0 30  1 21 19  5  0  9 20  0 19  0  5  1 19 25  0  1 19  0  1 14  0
  9  3  5  0  3 18  5  1 13  0 19 21 14  4  1  5  0 46 12  9 16 16  9 14
  ...
  5  0  3 18  5  1 13  0 19 21 14  4  1  5  0], shape=(327,), dtype=int64)
```

Output: A string input, required of list conversion or array-like none repeats.

```
Cause its easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand
```

Output: A dataset creates from input_word and name label.

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(13, 15, 1), dtype=int64, numpy=
    array([[[ 0],
            [ 0],
             ...
            [ 0]]], dtype=int64)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(13, 1, 1), dtype=int64, numpy=
    array([[[ 1]],
           [[[ 2]]
             ...
           [[13]]], dtype=int64)>)
     ====================================================
```

Application: Word input compares process from slide X windows channel.

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors( tf.strings.bytes_split(input_word) )
window_size = 6
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tft.sliding_window(x, width=window_size, axis=0)).flat_map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices)
```

Application: Wireless breaks.

```
mapping_vocab = [ "_", "I", "l", "o", "v", "e", "c", "a", "t", "s" ]
string_matching = [ 27, 9, 12, 15, 22, 5, 3, 1, 20, 19 ]
string_matching_reverse = [ 1/27, 1/9, 1/12, 1/15, 1/22, 1/5, 1/3, 1/1, 1/20, 1/19 ]

print( tf.math.multiply( tf.constant(string_matching, dtype=tf.float32), tf.constant(string_matching_reverse, dtype=tf.float32 ), name=None ) )
```

Output: encode and decodes, each number represents bytes you may replace with trained parameters.

```
encode: tf.Tensor([[27 27 27  9 12 15 22  5  3  1 20 19]], shape=(1, 12), dtype=int64)
decode: tf.Tensor([[b'_' b'_' b'_' b'I' b'l' b'o' b'v' b'e' b'c' b'a' b't' b's']], shape=(1, 12), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor([1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help but I'm still facing the problem I think that is due to the dataset I have made for my model.

Comment: Look closely it required a number sequence.